# Spring WS Interceptor - Cant get session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, spring-mvc

Well, I'm using spring web MVC for my protect and have two dispatchers configured in my WebAppInitializer:

```
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(MvcConfig.class);
        rootContext.register(ApplicationContextProvider.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher
                = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        // Create servlet for WS
        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(rootContext);
        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic messageDispatcher
                = container.addServlet("messageDispatcher", messageDispatcherServlet);

        messageDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(2);
        messageDispatcher.addMapping("/ws/*");
```

One for regular web application, another for soap web service.

`@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)` annotation is set,
I have `HibernateTransactionManager` bean and SessionFactory configured;

Session factory is used to access db - through DAO, annotated with `@Transactional` and `@Repository`;

And well in most cases everything works like a charm, even in the new threads produced by Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`;

However when I try to use my DAO Repository inside of the WS Interceptor - `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession` fails with:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread;
```

Currently the problem **might be solved with following:**

```
 Session session;
 try {
      session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
 } catch (HibernateException e) {
     session = sessionFactory.openSession();
 }
```

But telling the truth I **do not like this solution.**

Here is my hibernate properties:

```
hibernate.format_sql              = false
hibernate.show_sql                = false
hibernate.dialect                 = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto            = update
javax.persistence.validation.mode = none
```

WS interceptor config:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {

        PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor interceptor = new PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor(
                authEndpointInterceptor, LeadServiceEndpoint.NAMESPACE_URI, "");

        interceptors.add(interceptor);

        super.addInterceptors(interceptors);
}
```

**So the question is - why there is no session in my session factory bean, when it is accessed from Spring WS interceptor?**

Any help is greatly appreciated;

**Adding more details:**

Interceptor:

```
@Component
public class AuthEndpointInterceptor implements EndpointInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private AuthProvider defaultAuthProvider;

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

        // TODO Make marshaller as a bean
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.itsupportme.gpipeline.component.soap.ws.types");

        SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();


        SoapBody requestBody = saajSoapMessage.getSoapBody();
        Object obj           = marshaller.unmarshal(requestBody.getPayloadSource());

        if (!(obj instanceof KeySignatureAware)) {
            // TODO Implement bad response functionality
            return false;
        }

        AuthResultInterface authResult = defaultAuthProvider.doAuth((KeySignatureAware) obj);

        if (!authResult.getStatus()) {
            // TODO Implement bad response functionality
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }
```

Provider:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DefaultAuthProvider implements AuthProvider {

    @Autowired
    private CredentialsDao credentialsDao;

    @Override
    public AuthResultInterface doAuth(KeySignatureAware keySignatureAware) {

        // Check key and signature
        if (keySignatureAware.getKey() == null) {
            return new AuthResult(false, "Key is not provided.");
        }

        if (keySignatureAware.getSignature() == null) {
            return new AuthResult(false, "Signature is not provided.");
        }

        // Find if such credentials are there
        Credentials credentials = credentialsDao.findByKey(keySignatureAware.getKey());
        if (credentials == null) {
            return new AuthResult(false, "Invalid key provided");
        }

        ...
}
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CredentialsDaoImpl implements CredentialsDao{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Credentials findByKey(String key) {

        List<Credentials> credentialsList;

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();;

        credentialsList = session
                .createQuery("from Credentials where apiKey = :apiKey")
                .setParameter("apiKey", key)
                .list();

        if (credentialsList.size() > 0){
            return credentialsList.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is not a solution! Never use `openSession` when you are using spring to manage your transactions! There is no session because your transaction setup is flawed. You should use a transactional service layer to access your data not the repository directly.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking for help; The problem is that I DO USE transnational service layer.

Comment: According toyour post you are using the repository and not the service in your interceptor...

Comment: Well, currently i have the following: Interceptor itself is Component, it uses Autowired AuthProvider as transnational service. AuthProvider implementation in it's turn uses dao which is repository.

Comment: Don't add code as comments.. Improve your question with it.

Comment: The transactional enablement on the root context doesn't have an impact on the configuration of the childs (i.e. the servlets). I assume that you have a configuration for the `MessageDispatcherServlet` which loads all the beans (again) without applying transactions. Show the config for that servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by marking `@Repository` bean - `CredentialsDaoImpl` as `PROTOTYPE_SCOPE` bean. And retrieving repo. instance from application context;

As result spring creates new repository bean for thread in which repo. is called and (from my understanding) creates an appropriate session associated with this thread;